# Angular2 select initial object with ngValue

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set an initial value when filling a select, the data is coming from rest and loaded in the component.
The initial value is not set/updated after the

Getting the list to fill the select:

```
...
ngOnInit():any {

this.crudService.get(`/api/countries`).subscribe(data => {this.countries = data;});
...
```

Getting the model object witch has a Country:

```
...
this.crudService.get('/api/unions/default').subscribe(data => {
 this.union = data;
...
```

HTML:

```
...
<div class="col-md-2">
              <select *ngIf="union.country" [(ngModel)]="union.country" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.code}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

...

Everything works, I can select a country and it is correctly updated in the model but the initial value is not selected but existing in the model...
Any suggestions or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: In a near future, you should be able to pass a custom comparator function. See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the default value is assigned to `union.country` and it is an object (vs a primitive value), it needs to be the same instance, not only an object with the same content.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.

Comment: I'm just debugging a similar problem, and this confirmed my guess as to why the select wasn't binding to the value I was giving it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag `[compareWith]` inside your `select` area in HTML and

```
  compareByID(first: any, second: any) {
    return first && second && first.ID == second.ID;
  }
```

inside of you component.ts.

When i used `ngValue` to select the value, it's hasn't setting the default value on init.