# angular2 ngModel/ngValue select option object - equality across different instances

Tags: javascript, angular, equality, angular2-forms

Flavors of this question have been asked numerous times across the various versions of Angular2 prior to release.  However, I have yet to find anything that will produce the desired behavior (short of workarounds that I want to avoid) in the plunk here: [Select Object Problems](https://plnkr.co/edit/RUeqgo?p=preview)

My form select has 2-way binding via [(ngModel)] to an object, and then 'option' is generated via *ngFor for a list of similar objects (all differentiated by id).  In my research, it has been mentioned several times that Angular2 uses JavaScript object equivalence (by instance), so an object in the bound model that does not have the same instance will not match to the list.  Thus, it does not get presented as the "selected" item - breaking the "2-way" data binding.

However, I would like to define a way for these instances to match.  Some solutions that seem to be floating around on the internet have been attempted, but I am either missing a small piece or have implemented incorrectly.

Options I want to avoid:

- Binding to something other than the object (i.e. the id) in ngModel.  ngValue is a great help that I want to utilize
- Workarounds through change handlers
- Forcing the instances to match (I am getting objects from a data service, and do not want to redefine them all to match... that seems like needless waste of resources)

Ideally (and this seems to have been discussed as possible in several places that had solutions - solutions insufficient in my case), it would be possible to define a standard of equality for ngModel to use in place of object instance equality.

i.e. the latest attempt below, where h.id == a.id is defining the attribute "selected".  What I do not understand is why this "selected" attribute does not get rendered - is it blocked somehow by ngModel?  Setting selected='true' manually in the HTML seems to fix, but generating with [attr.selected] or any of the other variants that build a ng-reflect-selected='true' attribute does not seem to do the trick.

```
<div *ngFor='let a of activePerson.hobbyList ; let i=index; trackBy:a?.id'>

    <label for='personHobbies'>Hobby:</label>
    <select id='personHobbies' class='form-control'
        name='personHobbies' [(ngModel)]='activePerson.hobbyList[i]' #name='ngModel'>

        <option *ngFor='let h of hobbyListSelect; trackBy:h?.id' 
            [ngValue]='h' 
            [attr.selected]='h.id == a.id ? true : null'
        >
        {{h.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Some things I have tried:

- trackBy
- Binding to [selected]=, selected={{}}, and [attr.selected] (This seems close)

I have successfully achieved rendered HTML that looks like this:

```
<select ...>
    <option selected='true'>Selected</option>
    <option selected='false'>Not Selected</option>
    <!-- and variants, excluding with selected=null-->
</select>
```

But still no selected value when the object instance is different.  I have also struck out trying to find out what element in HTML or CSS is recording the selected value when the user selects a value (how ngModel handles, and what other options there might be for handling).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The goal is to get the "Change" button to change the underlying model and update the select boxes accordingly - I have focused my attempts on the "hobbyList."  I have tried on Firefox and Chrome.  Thanks!

Comment: As a resource to be offered with this bounty, I have found that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728121/angular2-select-initial-object-with-ngvalue) is completely true. However, there must be some way of setting the initial select option when using ngValue and comparing two objects.

Comment: Why not simply update the existing array data and use it instead of creating new data? It seems logical to me that creating new objects will break existing functionality. There's nothing wrong going on there, it's comparing objects instead of string primitives (which is what you expect), you'd have to modify the prototype to get what you want, but the right way would be to update your model data. You could also use an array of id numbers or strings instead of objects and that would work as well.

Comment: The array of selectable options as well as the object itself are coming from separate data services - so different instances.  I am hoping to work in a way consistent with the framework using ngValue, but if the framework doesn't support it, I will clearly have to work around.

My biggest surprise is honestly that forcing the "selected" attribute doesn't provide the desired behavior.  Typing "selected=true" in developer mode will work as desired, but doing the same through angular2 does not.  Moreover, attempting through angular2 prevents the developer mode edit from working.

Comment: The custom comparator function parameter is on the way ;) Track this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per @Klinki

> Currently there is no simple solution in angular 2, but in angular 4
>   this is already addressed since beta 6 using
>   [`compareWith`](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)
>   - see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13349

To illustrate the usage for the proposed case ([see plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/kf8Nk4X2twulzB4dC6GG?p=preview)):

```
<div *ngFor='let a of activePerson.hobbyList ; let i=index;'>

        <label for='personHobbies'>Hobby:</label> 
        <select id='personHobbies' class='form-control'
          name='personHobbies' [(ngModel)]='activePerson.hobbyList[i]'
          [compareWith]='customCompareHobby'>
          <option *ngFor='let h of hobbyListSelect;' [ngValue]='h'>{{h.name}}</option>
        </select>

</div>
...
customCompareHobby(o1: Hobby, o2: Hobby) {
    return o1.id == o2.id;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no simple solution in angular 2, but in angular 4 this is already addressed since beta 6 - see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13349

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: I am very appreciative of this answer, but it does not offer much without the link - please see the accepted answer for a contextual application that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [compareWith] solves this problem. Just change in the method compareObj the correct atribute for the Object your comparing.

```
<select [compareWith]="compareObj"  [(ngModel)]="selectedObjects">
   <option *ngFor="let object of objects" [ngValue]="object">
      {{object.name}}
   </option>
</select>

compareObj(o1: Object, o2: Object) {
   return o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get an object passed from somewhere that you want to make the selected one, just search the `hobbyListSelect` array for the matching item and assign the found item to `activePerson.hobbyList[i]`

Comment: His set of 3 constraints kill any normal approaches to make it work which is frustrating because reusing the objects solves it neatly as does matching on ids and I think there's a third possible solution (I tried a bunch of stuff but could never meet the constraints and get correct behavior).

It's a question where the answer may well be "redesign your program to work within the framework's constraints."

Comment: Some people don't care about how objects work and just want everything to magically work. This is what kills frameworks like Angular2 when every such feature is implemented because it makes it complex and hard to maintain for rare edge cases just to silence complaints of users ;-) In Dart you can just override the `equals` operator, but I guess suggesting a sane language is probably also not what is asked for here ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight-forward approach to using ngModel binding this way.
However, since you do not want to register event handlers separately, we may need to change the way the object is being assigned.
Also you need not assign id for select tag as it is not serving the purpose.
For the use case mentioned, I have modified it to see the two-way binding.

Find the component's constructor with model and printVal() is included just to test the change. Template does not include ngValue and ngModel, still it can work as expected.

```js
constructor() {
    this.activePerson = {id: 'a1',
        hobbyList : [
           {
             id: 'h4'
           },
           {
             id : 'h2'
           }
          ]
      }
      
    this.hobbyListSelect = [
        {
         id: 'h1'
        },
        {
         id : 'h2'
        },
        {
         id: 'h3'
        },
        {
         id : 'h4'
        }
      ];
  }

printVal($event,i) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.activePerson.hobbyList))
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor='let a of activePerson.hobbyList ; let i=index; trackBy:a?.id'>
        <label for='personHobbies'>Hobby:</label>
        <select name='personHobbies' 
        (change)=" activePerson.hobbyList[i] = hobbyListSelect[$event.target.selectedIndex];
        printVal($event,i)">
            <option *ngFor='let h of hobbyListSelect; trackBy:h?.id' 
                [selected]='(h.id == a.id) ? "selected" : null'
            >
            {{h.id}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `trackBy` is incorrect. It requires a function as an argument. In your case `trackBy: a => a && a.id`.